# Filter file list with an option to include recursion

Tags: python, list, file, recursion

I'm trying to write a few lines of code that allows the user to request a list of files in the provided directory but also allows for recursive.  I found this answer which is VERY close to what I want but it doesn't handle recursion.  I'm on Python 2.7.x

```
import glob
print glob.glob( '\myfavoritePath\' )
```

These examples below would return a filtered file list from the given path.

```
# basically providing same answers as OS would when doing a Dir
getFileList ( "/MyFavoritepPath/" )
getFileList ( "/MyFavoritepPath/*.txt" )
getFileList ( "/MyFavoritepPath/myFile*.txt" )
```

or

These examples would include results from the root as well as paths contained in the given folder.

```
getFileList ( "/MyFavoritepPath/ -r" )
getFileList ( "/MyFavoritepPath/*.txt -r" )
getFileList ( "/MyFavoritepPath/myFile*.txt -r" )
```

Final requirement is that this needs to be just a few lines of code.  Keeping this simple is very important.  It should include full list of all files and folders that match the given path.

Comment: Just FYI, but `glob.glob( '\myfavoritePath\' )` doesn't work because of improper backslash handling.

Comment: Thanks that is just a copy and paste bug with my original text.  I got it to give me results from the root folder provided.  I just can't make the recursion work.  THAT is what I'm hoping for some help on.

Comment: I've also looked at os.listdir(path) but the documentation says nothing about handling file filters or recursion.  I haven't had a chance to try it yet and will when I get time.  It would be good to here from any that has direct experience with this function as well.  Usually an API document would give examples of what it could handle so I'm thinking that it doesn't support it.